# Violación de segmento C++

Tags: c++

Tengo dos módulos, ClaseConjunto y modulo1.

Dentro de ClaseConjunto tengo 3 clases: TablaHash, ArbolTrie y ClaseConjunto.

ClaseConjunto tiene dos atributos, uno de la claseTablaHash y otro de tipo ArbolTrie.

El caso es que cuando desde 205.cpp llamo a dic.consulta(cadena) (dic es una variable de tipo ConjuntoPalabras), que a su vez llama a la función ar.consulta(palabra) (ar es el atributo de dic de tipo ArbolTrie) me da violación de segmento.

Cuando cambio la función consulta(cadena) por th.consulta(cadena) no me pasa este error. Es decir, que cuando consulto una tablahash no me da error y cuando consulto un ArbolTrie sí. Las funciones de consulta de estas dos clases están en ClaseConjunto.cpp.

205.cpp

```
#include "modulo1.h"
#include "ClaseConjunto.h"

ConjuntoPalabras dic;

void Meter(string cadena){
    dic.inserta(cadena);
}

void Borrar(string cadena){
    dic.elimina(cadena);
}

void Comprobar(string cadena){
    cout << cadena;
    if (!dic.consulta(cadena))
        cout << "[error]";
}



void procesarDiccionario(void){
    tipoToken token;
    string cadena;
    dic.vacia();
    //Vaciar el diccionario
    while (siguienteToken(token, cadena) && token != FINCOMANDO)
        if (token == PALABRA)
            Meter(cadena); //Borrar(cadena)
    cout << "[" << dic.nTotal() << " palabras]";
}

void procesarInsertar(void){
    tipoToken token;
    string cadena;
    //Vaciar el diccionario
    while (siguienteToken(token, cadena) && token != FINCOMANDO)
        if (token == PALABRA) {
            Meter(cadena);
            cout<<"aqui"; }
    cout << "[" << dic.nTotal() << " palabras]";
}

void procesarEliminar(void){
    tipoToken token;
    string cadena;
    //Vaciar el diccionario
    while (siguienteToken(token, cadena) && token != FINCOMANDO)
        if (token == PALABRA)
            Borrar(cadena); //Borrar(cadena)
    cout << "[" << dic.nTotal() << " palabras]";
}



void procesarTexto (void){
    extern void procesarComando(string cadena);
    tipoToken token;
    string cadena;
    while (siguienteToken(token, cadena) && token!= FINCOMANDO) {
        if (token==COMANDO)
            procesarComando(cadena);
        else if (token==PALABRA)
            Comprobar(cadena);
        else
            cout << cadena;
    }
}

void procesarComando (string cadena)
{

    istringstream ccad(cadena);
    string comando, param;
    ccad >> comando;
    if (comando=="texto") procesarTexto();
    else if (comando=="diccionario") procesarDiccionario();
    else if (comando=="insertar") procesarInsertar();
    else if (comando=="eliminar") procesarEliminar();
    else {
        ccad >> param;
        if (comando=="sugiere") procesarSugiere(param);
        else if (comando=="rimar") procesarRimar(param);
        else if (comando=="movil") procesarMovil(param);
        else if (comando=="autocorregir") procesarAutocorregir(param);
        else if (comando=="completar") procesarCompletar(param);
        else if (comando=="comodines") procesarComodines(param);
        else if (comando=="anagramas") procesarAnagramas(param);
        else if (comando=="resumen") procesarResumen(param);
    }
}



int main(){
    tipoToken token;
     string cadena;
     while (siguienteToken(token, cadena)) {
         if (token==COMANDO)
            procesarComando(cadena);
         else if (token!=FINCOMANDO)
            cout << cadena;
     }
}
```

ClaseConjunto.h

```
#ifndef CLASECONJUNTO_H
#define CLASECONJUNTO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>
#include "modulo1.h"
using namespace std;

class TablaHash{
    private:
        list<string> *lista;
        unsigned long long nElem;
        unsigned long long B; //numero de cubetas
    public:
        TablaHash();
        ~TablaHash();
        void inserta(string palabra);
        void elimina(string palabra);
        bool consulta(string palabra);
        string completar(string palabra);
        void vacia(void);
        int nTotal(void){
            return nElem;
        }
        int indice(string palabra);
};

class NodoTrie {
    friend class ArbolTrie;
    private:
        char c;
        NodoTrie *siguiente;
        NodoTrie *hijo;
    public:
        NodoTrie(char c, NodoTrie*siguiente, NodoTrie*hijo);
        NodoTrie();
        ~NodoTrie ();
        NodoTrie* consulta (char c);
        void inserta(char c);
        void elimina();
        void PonMarca();
        void QuitaMarca();
        bool HayMarca();
        void tomaNuevo (char letra);
};

class ArbolTrie {
    private:
        NodoTrie*raiz;
        int nElem;
    public:
        ArbolTrie();
        ~ArbolTrie();
        void insertar(string palabra);
        void eliminar(string palabra);
        bool consultar(string palabra);
        void vacia(void);
        int nTotal(void) {return nElem;};
};


class ConjuntoPalabras {
    private:
        TablaHash th;
        ArbolTrie ar;
    public:
        ConjuntoPalabras ();
        void inserta (string palabra){
            th.inserta(palabra);
            ar.insertar(palabra);
        }
        void elimina (string palabra){
            th.elimina(palabra);
            ar.eliminar(palabra);
        }
        bool consulta(string palabra){
            return ar.consultar(palabra);
        }
        string completar(string palabra){
            return th.completar(palabra);
        }
        void vacia (void){
            th.vacia();
        }
        int nTotal(void) {
            return th.nTotal();
        }

};

#endif
```

ClaseConjunto.cpp

```
#include "ClaseConjunto.h"

NodoTrie::NodoTrie(){
    c = ' ';
    siguiente = NULL;
    hijo = NULL;
}

NodoTrie::~NodoTrie(){
    delete siguiente;
    delete hijo;
}

NodoTrie::NodoTrie(char c, NodoTrie* siguiente, NodoTrie* hijo){
    this->c = c;
    this->siguiente = siguiente;
    this->hijo = hijo;
}

NodoTrie* NodoTrie::consulta(char c){
    NodoTrie * tmp = siguiente;
    while (tmp != NULL && tmp->c < c){
        tmp = tmp->siguiente;
    }
    if (tmp != NULL && tmp->c == c){
        return tmp->hijo;
    }
    else return NULL;
}


ArbolTrie::ArbolTrie(){
    raiz = NULL;
}

ArbolTrie::~ArbolTrie(){
    delete raiz;
}

bool ArbolTrie::consultar(string palabra) {
    NodoTrie * pos = raiz;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
        if (pos->consulta(palabra[i]) == NULL) return false;
        else pos = pos->consulta(palabra[i]);
    }
    if (pos->HayMarca()) return true;
    else return false;
}

TablaHash::TablaHash(){
    nElem = 0;
    this->B = 500;
    lista = new list<string>[B];
}

bool TablaHash::consulta(string palabra){
    if (tipoCadena(palabra) == MAYUS || tipoCadena(palabra) == FRASE)
        {
            string pal_minus = minuscula(palabra);
            unsigned long long index = indice(pal_minus);
            list<string>::iterator i = lista[index].begin();
            while (i != lista[index].end() && *i != pal_minus){
                i++;
            }
        if (i != lista[index].end() || *i == pal_minus)
            return true;
        }

    unsigned long long index = indice(palabra);
    list<string>::iterator i = lista[index].begin();
    while (i != lista[index].end() && *i != palabra){
        i++;
    }
    if (i != lista[index].end() || *i == palabra)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lo que me gustaría saber es por qué al llamar a la funcion ar.consultar(palabra) me da una violación de segmento en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: Por favor, proporciona un [mcve]. No me creo que sea necesario **todo** ese código  para reproducir tu problema. Un saludo.